# YouTube channel subscribe for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am using the YouTube API within my app. Users can log in with their Google+ account. I would like the user to be able to subscribe to certain YouTube channels.

There seems to be something for web here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/subscribe/

But I can't find something suited to Android. Am I missing something from the documentation or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a specific Android library to subscribe an authenticated user to a specific channel.  Just send an authenticated POST request to the [`subscriptions/insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) endpoint with the `channelId` of the channel you want to subscribe to with the `Part` param `snippet`:

```
HTTP POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Request body:

```
{
    "snippet": {
        "resourceId": {
            "channelId": "XXXXX" // channel ID you want to subscribe to
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do what you suggested but it doesn't work.
Are you sure this is for Android?
Which would be my API key?

so.. according to your answer if I run this

    curl https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions -d "part={'snippet':{'resourceId':{'channelId':'CHANNEL_ID'}}}&key=MY_UNKNOWN_API_KEY"

it should work?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: @JFValdes My answer is language and platform agnostic, it should work on any platform.  If you're using Google's official Android SDK for YouTube, the call you make might be different.  Your API key should be in your app in the Google Developer Console.

Comment: But there is no API Key when registering my app for android. Are you really sure this is possible to do with android? 

I actually have API Key when using gcm push, for example, but I don't have any when using google push login or youtube sdk.

Comment: @JFValdes are you using this?  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3  Just make sure the user is authenticated with OAuth before making the request.

Comment: Yes I am. In fact this is how my developer console looks like https://gyazo.com/6b173154b0d8e8854305cbf354dd96d9, but it returns

    {
     "error": {
      "errors": [
       {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "message": "Login Required",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
       }
      ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Login Required"
     }
    }

Comment: Id doesn't make sense anyway. Who am I subscribing? I'm only sending my apikey and the channel ID. But how does google know who do I want to subscribe to that channel?

Comment: @JFValdes The error is telling you exactly what is wrong.  You need to have your user authorize your application with OAuth before making the request: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#console_name

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it, but just to make sure.. I'm suscribing to the mobile ownser, isn't it? I want to susbscribe to the users of my app, not myself. It's weird because in the call that you say there is no kind of identification of that user.

Comment: @JFValdes I'm not sure how the authentication flow works in the Android SDK, but you would need to have the user of your app sign in with their username and password, get the auth token from the OAuth callback, and use that token to make an authenticated request on behalf of the user that just logged in.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but for example, I can't add a youtube scope to my token request because it's unavaible in android.

Comment: @JFValdes found any solutions yet , i'm stuck here too?

Comment: @JFValdes Have you find any solution to this problem ? i am also stucked here for a week and didn't found any solution .

Comment: kindly tell me what is snippet and what is api key in link

Answer (score 0):

I found we can subcription with request body as:

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "resourceId": {
      "channelId": "your channel Id",
        "kind": "youtube#channel"
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://mshibanami.github.io/en/blog/subscriptions-insert-error/

Comment: is there any source code available to learn more about the implementation ?