# How to implement an embedded youtube subscribe button android?

Tags: android, youtube-api

How can I add an embedded YouTube subscribe button to my android app? I need a button that subscribes them to my channel but stays in my app like the web button, but for android. I tried a subscription link but it takes them out of my app.

Comment: [You can find the implementations here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914226/youtube-channel-subscribe-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use [subscriptions.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert) from the Youtube Data API to add a subscription for the authenticated user's channel. Make it that when the button is pressed, this part of code executes.

code snippet:

```
try {
        // Authorize the request.
        Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "addsubscription");

        // This object is used to make YouTube Data API requests.
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
                "youtube-cmdline-addsubscription-sample").build();

        // We get the user selected channel to subscribe.
        // Retrieve the channel ID that the user is subscribing to.
        String channelId = getChannelId();
        System.out.println("You chose " + channelId + " to subscribe.");

        // Create a resourceId that identifies the channel ID.
        ResourceId resourceId = new ResourceId();
        resourceId.setChannelId(channelId);
        resourceId.setKind("youtube#channel");

        // Create a snippet that contains the resourceId.
        SubscriptionSnippet snippet = new SubscriptionSnippet();
        snippet.setResourceId(resourceId);

        // Create a request to add the subscription and send the request.
        // The request identifies subscription metadata to insert as well
        // as information that the API server should return in its response.
        Subscription subscription = new Subscription();
        subscription.setSnippet(snippet);
        YouTube.Subscriptions.Insert subscriptionInsert =
                youtube.subscriptions().insert("snippet,contentDetails", subscription);
        Subscription returnedSubscription = subscriptionInsert.execute();

        // Print information from the API response.
        System.out.println("\n================== Returned Subscription ==================\n");
        System.out.println("  - Id: " + returnedSubscription.getId());
        System.out.println("  - Title: " + returnedSubscription.getSnippet().getTitle());

    }
```

Here's a related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914226/youtube-channel-subscribe-for-android) for additional reference.

Comment: Is there a app source  anywhere  that I could look at to learn from??